# How to turn off the screen using tasker in android?

Tags: android, screen, display, tasker

Hi guys I wanna turn off and on the screen using tasker it also supports java and shell scripts I want the script be off but everything work like touch input but I couldn't find a way to do this without locking the device which disables touch input plz help me.

Comment: could you please clarify what do you exactly need? Having the script off and having it doing stuff at the same time is contradictionary.

do you need to do stuff when screen is off or want to do it with screen on? WHAT do you want tasker to do? Clicking? typing? more info needed

Comment: Hi tnx, for the reply.dude I want the script be off like when you're on a call.But touch should work like when screen is on.I just mean to cut the power it gets to screen to turn it on but touch should work.So when I click I see nth like phone is off but it's not and everything is working just I don't wanna see.I want tasker to do this.

Answer (score 1):

you can have tasker do some **limited** stuff while the screen is off, but being able to click anything by yourself while the screen is off is impossible (in Tasker)

you can, however, try this application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nkahoang.screenstandby

Comment: Tnx but my device isn't rooted is there any similar app works without root?

Comment: Ok tnx btw if ya found out there anything plz let me know.

Comment: but did you even try that app? it also has a non-root method, which is "not as effective & battery saving as root"

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work :/ it just goes out of the app immediately after the first setup

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry